# AngularJS slider - can't get directive to work

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, slider

Hi I'm trying to make a slider I got off the internet to work, but, I keep getting errors. In gallery.html, when I put the slider element at the top I get nothing, when I put it at the bottom I get errors. The error is something along the lines

```
Error: [$compile:tplrt] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$compile/tplrt?p0=slider&p1=partials%2Fgallery.html
```

---

Changed my code to match the suggestions in one of the comments.

I'm no longer getting the error to do with not have just 1 root element. Now, I can't get the next and previous to work. It just redirects me to the main page.
Note: 
- gallery.html and slider.html are in a folder called partials
- all the images are in a folder called img

Thanks in advance!

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myapp">
<head>
  <!-- ANGULAR IMPORTS -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ui-router-master/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular-animate.js"></script>

    <!-- JS FILES -->
    <script src="js/controller.js"></script>
  <script src="js/directives.js"></script>
  <link href='css/app.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body class="container">
  <div class="navbar">
    <a class="brand" href="#">Quick Start</a>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a ui-sref="state1">State 1</a></li>
      <li><a ui-sref="state2">State 2</a></li>
      <li><a ui-sref="gallery">Gallery</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="dynamiccontent">
    <div ui-view></div>
  </div>         

  <!-- App Script -->
  <script>
    /** MAIN ANGULAR VAR */
    var myapp = angular.module('myapp', [
      /**IMPORT DEPENDENCIES*/
      'ui.router',
      'ngAnimate',
      /**FILE DEPENDENCIES*/ 
      'appController', 
      'slider.directive'
    ]);

    /** UI-ROUTING */
    myapp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){  
      // For any unmatched url, send to /state1
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/state1")

      $stateProvider
        .state('state1', {
            url: "/state1",
            templateUrl: "partials/state1.html"
        })
        .state('state1.list', {
          url: "/list",
          templateUrl: "partials/state1.list.html",
          controller: 'state1controller'
        })
        .state('gallery', {
          url: "/gallery",
          templateUrl: "partials/gallery.html",
          controller: 'slidercontroller'
        }) 
        .state('state2', {
          url: "/state2",
          templateUrl: "partials/state2.html"
        })
        .state('state2.list', {
          url: "/list",
          templateUrl: "partials/state2.list.html",
          controller: 'state2controller'
        });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**controller.js**

```
var appController = angular.module('appController',[]);

appController.controller('state1controller', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.items = ["A", "List", "Of", "Items"];
}]);

appController.controller('state2controller', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.things = ["A", "List", "Of", "Items"];
}]);

appController.controller('slidercontroller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.pictures=[{src:'img1.png',title:'Pic 1'},{src:'img2.jpg',title:'Pic 2'},{src:'img3.jpg',title:'Pic 3'},{src:'img4.png',title:'Pic 4'},{src:'img5.png',title:'Pic 5'}]; 
}]);
```

**directive.js**

```
 angular.module('slider.directive', [])
  .directive('slider', function ($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    replace: true,
    scope:{
      pictures: '='
    },
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
    scope.currentIndex=0;

    scope.next=function(){
      scope.currentIndex<scope.pictures.length-1?scope.currentIndex++:scope.currentIndex=0;
    };

    scope.prev=function(){
      scope.currentIndex>0?scope.currentIndex--:scope.currentIndex=scope.pictures.length-1;
    };

    scope.$watch('currentIndex',function(){
      scope.pictures.forEach(function(image){
        image.visible=false;
      });
      scope.pictures[scope.currentIndex].visible=true;
    });

    /* Start: For Automatic slideshow*/

    var timer;

    var sliderFunc=function(){
      timer=$timeout(function(){
        scope.next();
        timer=$timeout(sliderFunc,5000);
      },5000);
    };

    sliderFunc();

    scope.$on('$destroy',function(){
      $timeout.cancel(timer);
    });

    /* End : For Automatic slideshow*/

    },
    templateUrl:'partials/slider.html'
  }
});
```

**gallery.html**

```
<slider pictures="pictures"></slider>
```

**slider.html**

```
<div class="slider">
    <div class="slide" ng-repeat="image in pictures">
        <img ng-src="img/{{image.src}}"/>
    </div>
    <div class="arrows">
        <a href="#" ng-click="prev()"><img src="img/left-arrow.png"/></a>
        <a href="#" ng-click="next()"><img src="img/right-arrow.png"/></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure partials/gallery.html exists?

Comment: Also - directive templates can only have one root element. Try to wrap slider and its div in an outer div.

Comment: When I try and wrap everything in gallery.html in a div it sends me into an infinite loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing several concerns here. `partials/gallery.html` is used as a template for your directive and your page. This leads to the directive being used itself in it's own template.

The solution is to remove your directive code from gallery.html and use it in a new file `slider.html`.

### directive.js

```
.directive('slider', function ($timeout) {
  return {
    ...
    templateUrl:'partials/slider.html'
```

### slider.html

```
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide" ng-repeat="image in images">
    <img ng-src="img/{{image.src}}"/>
  </div>
  <div class="arrows">
    <a href="#" ng-click="prev()"><img src="img/left-arrow.png"/></a>
    <a href="#" ng-click="next()"><img src="img/right-arrow.png"/></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

### gallery.html

```
<slider images="pictures"/>
```

Comment: I made these changes and nothing came up. I see what you mean, but, should gallery.html just be

<div class="slider">

or should it be 

<slider images="pictures"/>

Comment: I made an error while copy'n'pasting. Changed slider.html and gallery.html

Comment: I fully understand this logic and it seems like it should work, but, I can't get it to work at the moment. I get the arrows coming up but the pictures don't =/

Comment: Seems like you are iterating `pictures` while the variable in your scope is called `images`. Does this help?

Comment: Nope =( I think images in my directive scope is supposed to equal the JSON data in pictures. I've changed it to be <slider pictures="pictures"></slider> in gallery.html for simplicity, and then changed all the instances of the word "images" in directives.js to pictures, so I don't get confused.

Comment: Please try `<img ng-src="'img/'+image.src"/>`

Comment: OK, I guess this is progress! I now have that icon appearing that comes up when there is supposed to be an image but can't find it? I think that's what it means anyway...

Comment: This should be easy to fix by using the debugging tools of your browser. It is hard to tell, what is going wrong now, without further information. Double check the paths of your image requests and maybe output your picture url `{{image}}` somewhere in your html template.

Comment: OK awesome, thank you for all your help so far! I have the images coming up, but, the arrows don't work lol. Problem after problem haha. It just redirects me to state1 page because it doesn't recognise the address when I press an arrow, like I specified when defining my states

Comment: The arrows technically are working. I console.logged the index of the current picture and it was going up and down, but the images aren't changing

Comment: I'm not sure my code in the arrows bit is correct, in particular the href bit. Also, I'm using stateProvider so shouldn't I be using ui-sref?

Comment: Since you are not navigating, there is no need to use `ui-sref`. Also you logged the index of the current picture, so why should the arrow bit have an error then? It's hard to tell, what's going wrong, everything seems fine. Maybe if you could make a plunker, I could be of further help.

Comment: I've made a github repository https://github.com/IdrisAbdul-Hussein/Portfolio-Test.git

I hope this helps, I appreciate its hard to know whats going on!

Comment: @IdrisAH Had a look. You always showed every picture, so I added `ng-show` and it works for me now: `<img ng-src="img/{{image.src}}" ng-show="image.visible" />`. Hope this helps and btw I would appreciate any upvotes ;)

Comment: Ahhhh dude thanks so much!! Really appreciate all the help! Believe me, I've been trying to give you upvotes but I don't have the rep for it yet. Once I have 15 rep I will upvote this for sure!!

Answer (score 0):

First off - the error does have to do with the root element.
https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/tplrt

```
Template for directive '{0}' must have exactly one root element. {1}
```

Now that you fixed that issue - your infinite loop is called because you're trying to populate the slider directive with gallery.html - but in that template, you're calling the slider directive. So that's an infinite loop.